# Can not install Apantan Eclipse PlugIn

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install Apantana Eclipse Plugin however i am getting this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: GWT Designer Editor 2.6.0.r36x201206111227 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group 2.6.0.r36x201206111227)
Missing requirement: Apache Xerces-J 2.9.0.v201101211617 (org.apache.xerces 2.9.0.v201101211617) requires 'bundle javax.xml [1.3.4,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: GWT Designer UiBinder Support 2.6.0.r36x201206111227 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.UiBinder 2.6.0.r36x201206111227)
To: bundle org.eclipse.wb.core.xml 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: GWT Designer Editor 2.6.0.r36x201206111227 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group 2.6.0.r36x201206111227)
To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.UiBinder [2.6.0.r36x201206111227]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: WindowBuilder Core for XML GUI's 1.5.0.r36x201206111216 (org.eclipse.wb.core.xml 1.5.0.r36x201206111216)
To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Structured Source XML Model 1.1.503.v201102102045 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 1.1.503.v201102102045)
To: bundle org.apache.xerces [2.9.0,3.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 1.1.103.v201101122108 (org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui 1.1.103.v201101122108)
To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.xml.core [1.1.500,1.2.0)
```

I tried to add xerces (i hope i did that correctly) to classpath but i still get this error message.

```
System Config:
Win7 64bit
Eclipse HELIOS ver 3.6.2
Java 1.6.0_21.
```

I would appreciate any help/clue.

Thanks.

Comment: Retry it with the current release, Juno SR2, which is 2 years newer.

Comment: Thanks. That works, now i can install the plugins.